# Habilitar Instagram Feed na home (index) do site

Tags: wordpress, plugin-wordpress, instagram-api

Como faço para colocar o feed do plugin Instagram Feed na minha página inicial?

As demais é tranquilo, porém na inicial não estou conseguindo.

Comment: Segue o exemplo: [instagram-feed cols=10 num=10 showheader=false width=100 buttontext="texto" followtext="texto"]

Comment: Assim eu uso nas páginas que crio. Eu preciso por na home (que não tem o arquivo editável, igual as demais páginas que eu crio).

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Vá em aparência->editor

No canto direito da tela, procure o arquivo index.php ("modelo da página principal"), em seguida cole esse código na parte em que desejar exibir o feed.

> echo do_shortcode("[instagram-feed]");

Só isso.